# Why is the code in the tidymodels.org tutorial not working?

Tags: r, tidymodels, recipe

I am following the tutorial in the "Preprocess your data with recipes" section of the Get Started section of tidymodels.org.

When I come up to the following code, Cloud R waits for a bit, then times out of the session, not executing the code. Would anyone have an idea why that is?

Thanks.

```
flights_fit <- flights_wflow %>%  fit(data = train_data)
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you clicked on the ["Test Drive on RStudio Cloud" button here](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/) and it would not run? Can you outline what happens for you and [post an issue here](https://github.com/tidymodels/tidymodels.org/issues)? FYI we intend those buttons to work.

Comment: Hi Julia. I was assembling code in my own workspace in Cloud by copying from the Get Started article. I now see that in the code in your workspace, you reduce the data to 20% of original. When I follow this in your workspace, I achieve the fit. But when I do the same in my workspace, I still get a time-out and do not achieve the fit. Curious, that's all.